# $\binom{n}{1}\sin(\alpha)+\binom{n}{2}\sin(2\alpha)+...\binom{n}{n}\sin(n\alpha) =2^n\cos^n\big(\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)\sin\big(\frac{n\alpha}{2}\big)$.

Tags: combinatorics

I have to prove the following identity:

$$\binom{n}{1} \sin(\alpha) + \binom{n}{2} \sin(2 \alpha) + ... \binom{n}{n} \sin(n \alpha) = 2^n \cos^n \bigg( \dfrac{\alpha}{2} \bigg ) \sin \left( \dfrac{n \alpha}{2} \right)$$

with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. I tried manipulating what I already knew:

$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k = 0} ^ n \binom{n}{k} x^k$$

But I couldn't come up with anything that would get me to the desired form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} \sin(r \alpha) &=& Im \left( \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (e^{i \alpha})^r \right) \\
&=& Im \left( (1+e^{i \alpha})^n \right) \\
&=& Im \left( (1+\cos( \alpha)+i \sin( \alpha)^n \right) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the double angle formulas $\cos( \alpha)=2\cos^2( \alpha)-1$ and $\sin( \alpha)=2\sin( \alpha/2)\cos( \alpha/2)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&=& Im \left( ( 2 \cos( \alpha/2 )( \cos( \alpha/2 ) +i \sin( \alpha/2 ) \right)^n)  \\
&=&   2^n \cos^n ( \alpha/2 ) Im( e^{i n\alpha/2 } ) \\
&=&   2^n \cos^n ( \alpha/2 ) \sin ( n \alpha/2 ).  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Take the imaginary part of$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\exp ik\alpha=(1+\exp i\alpha)^n-1=2^n\cos^n\frac{\alpha}{2}\exp\frac{in\alpha}{2}-1$$to get$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\sin k\alpha=2^n\cos^n\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{n\alpha}{2}.$$